# Trying to get my Java IRC Bot to parse and write to an preexisting XML file

Tags: java, xml, xpath, bots, irc

I'm a total Java virgin, and I've been stumbling slowly but surely in developing an IRC bot for my friends. So far, I've gotten nearly all of the features in working order. But, I'm really wracking my brain over this problem here, my bot so far can reply with a link, but every week, I have to change the link in the java file manually and recompile the whole thing. So, I want it to be able to parse the pertinent values from an XML file in the same directory the bot's java files are in, and be able to update those same values through an IRC client.

```
import org.jibble.pircbot.*;

import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.*;
import org.xml.sax.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;



public class ModBot extends PircBot {

static String inputFile = "./botdata.xml";
static String outputFile = "./botdata.xml";

public ModBot() {
    setLogin("ModBot");
    this.setName("ModBot");
    setVersion(" ");
}

public void onMessage(String channel, String sender, String login, String hostname, String message) {

if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("!lolcat")) {
sendMessage(channel, sender + "http://i.imgur.com/4IX4cUL.jpg");
}

if (message.startsWith("!updatelolcat ")) {
    if(login.equals("Mainmod"));
    String changelolcat = message.substring(14);


}
}
}
```

And the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE botdata [
<!ELEMENT botdata (lolcat,partytime,start,end)>
<!ELEMENT lolcat (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT partytime (start,end)>
<!ELEMENT start (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT end (#PCDATA)>
]>
<botdata>
<lolcat>http://i.imgur.com/4IX4cUL.jpg</lolcat>
<partytime>
<start>8:45:30</start>
<end>11:00:00</end>
</partytime>
</botdata>
```

What I want to do is take whatever "changelolcat" is, and overwrite the current link in the XML, and then a way to read from the same XML to send what's in "lolcat" to anyone replying "!lolcat". I've been going through xpath and jdom and stuff, and I just can't make sense of it. What I've read with methods using xpath looks promising, and I'd prefer to use it because it's prettier to read.

EDIT:

It worked, I put in

```
try {DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

        DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

        Document document = documentBuilder.parse("botdata.xml");

        Node botdata = document.getElementsByTagName("botdata").item(0);

        NodeList nodes = botdata.getChildNodes();

        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {

            Node element = nodes.item(i);

            if ("lolcat".equals(element.getNodeName())) {
                element.setTextContent(changelolcat);
            }


        }

        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();

        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(document);

        StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(new File("botdata.xml"));
        transformer.transform(domSource, streamResult);
    }catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
        pce.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TransformerException tfe) {
        tfe.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException sae) {
        sae.printStackTrace();
    }
```

after String changelolcat = message.substring(14);

EDIT: I figured out how to parse from my XML to send what's in a node as a message, does this look right? I feel like I'm not supposed to keep copying the doc builder over and over in different methods

```
        if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("!lolcat")) {
    try {
    DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory =                 

    DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

    DocumentBuilder documentBuilder =                       

    documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

    Document document = documentBuilder.parse(botxml);
                XPathFactory xpathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xpath = xpathFactory.newXPath();
                String lolcat = xpath.evaluate("//lolcat", document);

    sendMessage(channel, sender + lolcat);
    } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to use the `javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder` to parse your xml file into `javax.swing.text.Document`, which provides a great interface for getting and modifying individual elements and their values. You can then write the modified document back to the original file, overwriting it with the new version.

Here are some links to the relevant javadocs:

- [Document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Document.html)
- [DocumentBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html)

You might also want to look at the javadocs for the DocumentBuilderFactory object, which is definitely the best way to generate DocumentBuilders.